# how does change key name in json php

Tags: php, json

In below json object I need to change **Item1** (Key name) to **Item**. Is it possible.

```
"JournalEntry":{  
  "ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID":1,
  "CompanyID":"US-1",
  "Note":null,
  "Item":{  
     "ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID":null,
     "OriginalEntryDocumentItemReferenceItemID":1,
  },
  "Item1":{  
     "ObjectNodeSenderTechnicalID":null,
     "OriginalEntryDocumentItemReferenceItemID":2,
    }
 }
```

Comment: Alternatively rebuild the array_keys() index from the subarray. And array_combine() the swapped/renamed keys back in again. -- Also please always include prior attempts, research and a concrete problem description in questions. ("Help me" is not a question.)

Comment: Actually, I don't have any idea about this. Can you give any link regarding my queries? @mario

Comment: http://php.net/array_keys, http://php.net/array_combine, though a simple assignment using the array keys might suffice.

Comment: Thanks @mario It is not an Array to use array function.

Comment: `JSON_decode($xyz, TRUE)`, then you have an array.

Comment: I have already tried this action. But this function converts my object to the string. Not an array.

Comment: Prior coding attempts **must** be described in the question, not alluded to in the comments.